# Is Coin Change Algorithm That Output All Combinations Still Solvable By DP?

Tags: c++, algorithm

For example, total amount should be 5 and I have coins with values of 1 and 2. Then there are 3 ways of combinations:

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 2
1 2 2
```

I've seen some posts about how to calculate total number of combinations with dynamic programming or with recursion, but I want to output all the combinations like my example above. I've come up with a recursive solution below.

It's basically a backtracking algorithm, I start with the smallest coins first and try to get to the total amount, then I remove some coins and try using second smallest coins ... You can run my code below in http://cpp.sh/

The total amount is 10 and the available coin values are 1, 2, 5 in my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


vector<vector<int>> res;
vector<int> values;
int total = 0;

void helper(vector<int>& curCoins, int current, int i){

    int old = current;

    if(i==values.size())
        return;

    int val = values[i];

    while(current<total){
        current += val;
        curCoins.push_back(val);
    }

    if(current==total){
        res.push_back(curCoins);
    }


    while (current>old) {
        current -= val;
        curCoins.pop_back();

        if (current>=0) {
            helper(curCoins, current, i+1);
        }
    }


}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {       

    total = 10;
    values = {1,2,5};
    vector<int> chosenCoins;

    helper(chosenCoins, 0, 0);

    cout<<"number of combinations: "<<res.size()<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<res.size(); i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<res[i].size(); j++) {
            if(j!=0)
                cout<<" ";
            cout<<res[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a better solution to output all the combinations for this problem? Dynamic programming?

EDIT:

My question is is this problem solvable using dynamic programming?

Thanks for the help. I've implemented the DP version here: [Coin Change DP Algorithm Print All Combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33353227/coin-change-dp-algorithm-print-all-combinations)

Comment: I don't think an exhaustive search will run any faster using dynamic programming techniques..

Comment: Is there a problem your trying to solve, or just [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: You don't show the lone 5 in your short example, which is a legitimate way to give a sum of 5.

Comment: @n.m. Oh, you are right, I just changed that

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331 The problem is I don't know how to solve it with DP now that I need to print all combinations...

Comment: For DP, `solutions(n) = {solutions(n - 1) + coin1} + {solutions(n - 2) + coin2} + {solutions(n - 5) + coin5}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DP solution:

We have

```
{solutions(n)} = Union ({solutions(n - 1) + coin1},
                        {solutions(n - 2) + coin2},
                        {solutions(n - 5) + coin5})
```

So in code:

```
using combi_set = std::set<std::array<int, 3u>>;

void append(combi_set& res, const combi_set& prev, const std::array<int, 3u>& values)
{
    for (const auto& p : prev) {
        res.insert({{{p[0] + values[0], p[1] + values[1], p[2] + values[2]}}});   
    }
}

combi_set computeCombi(int total)
{
    std::vector<combi_set> combis(total + 1);

    combis[0].insert({{{0, 0, 0}}});
    for (int i = 1; i <= total; ++i) {
        append(combis[i], combis[i - 1], {{1, 0, 0}});
        if (i - 2 >= 0) { append(combis[i], combis[i - 2], {{0, 1, 0}}); }
        if (i - 5 >= 0) { append(combis[i], combis[i - 5], {{0, 0, 1}}); }
    }
    return combis[total];
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/GX5gzA).

Comment: I've implemented it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33353227/coin-change-dp-algorithm-print-all-combinations     But it seems a bit slow..

Comment: @Arch1tect, I was hoping you can help me I have a similar question to your post here but when you say all combinations, I am assuming non-distinct. Ex:  Using Coins {1, 2, 5} and N = 10, There are actually 128 ways. Can this be solved using DP? My Code is below

Answer (score 1):

Exhaustive search is unlikely to be 'better' with dynamic programming, but here's a possible solution:

Start with a 2d array of combination strings, arr[value][index] where value is the total worth of the coins. Let X be target value;

starting from arr[0][0] = "";
for each coin denomination n, from i = 0 to X-n you copy all the strings from arr[i] to arr[i+n] and append n to each of the strings.

for example with n=5 you would end up with
arr[0][0] = "", arr[5][0] = "5" and arr[10][0] = "5 5"

Hope that made sense. Typical DP would just count instead of having strings (you can also replace the strings with int vector to keep count instead)

Comment: to clarify; the typical dp would be a lot faster since for any number of combinations you've calculated thus far, the adding only requires a summation of counts, whereas keeping track of the individual combinations would force u to do some kind of copy on each of the counters.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have `K` the total size of the output your are expecting (the total number of coins in all the combinations). Obviously you can not have a solution that runs faster than `O(K)`, if you actually need to output all them. As `K` can be very large, this will be a very long running time, and in the worst case you will get little profit from the dynamic programming.

However, you still can do better than your straightforward recursive solution. Namely, you can have a solution running in `O(N*S+K)`, where `N` is the number of coins you have and `S` is the total sum. This will not be better than straightforward solution for the worst possible `K`, but if `K` is not so big, you will get it running faster than your recursive solution.

This `O(N*S+K)` solution can be relatively simply coded. First you run the standard DP solution to find out for each sum `current` and each `i` whether the sum `current` can be composed of first `i` coin types. You do not yet calculate all the solutions, you just find out whether at least one solution exists for each `current` and `i`. Then, you write a recursive function similar to what you have already written, but before you try each combination, you check using you DP table whether it is worth trying, that is, whether at least one solution exists. Something like:

```
void helper(vector<int>& curCoins, int current, int i){
    if (!solutionExists[current, i]) return; 
    // then your code goes
```

this way *each* branch of the recursion tree will finish in finding a solution, and therefore the total recursion tree size will be `O(K)`, and the total running time will be `O(N*S+K)`.

Note also that all this is worth only if you really need to output all the combinations. If you need to do something else with the combinations you get, it is very probable that you do not actually need all the combinations and you may adapt the DP solution for that. For example, if you want to print only `m`-th of all solutions, this can be done in `O(N*S)`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make two passes over the data structure (a hash table will work well as long as you've got a relatively small number of coins).

The first one finds all unique sums less than the desired total (actually you could stop perhaps at 1/2 the desired total) and records the simplest way (least additions required) to obtain that sum. This is essentially the same as the DP.

The second pass then goes starts at the desired total and works its way backwards through the data to output all ways that the total can be generated.

This ends up being a two stage approach of what Petr is suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

The actual amount of non distinct valid combinations for amounts {1, 2, 5} and N = 10 is 128, using a pure recursive exhaustive technique (Code below). My question is can an exhaustive search be improved with memoization/dynamic programming. If so, how can I modify the algorithm below to incorporate such techniques.

```
public class Recursive {

    static int[] combo = new int[100];
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        int n = 10;
        int[] amounts = {1, 2, 5};
        ways(n, amounts, combo, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public static void  ways(int n, int[] amounts, int[] combo, int startIndex, int sum, int index) {
        if(sum == n) {
            printArray(combo, index);
        }

        if(sum > n) {
            return;
        }


        for(int i=0;i<amounts.length;i++) {
            sum = sum + amounts[i];
            combo[index] = amounts[i];
            ways(n, amounts, combo, startIndex, sum, index + 1);
            sum = sum - amounts[i];
        }
    }

    public static void printArray(int[] combo, int index) {
        for(int i=0;i < index; i++) {
            System.out.print(combo[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```